# the compiled css file of main sass file not updating when updating and saving an imported partial sass file

Tags: import, compass-sass

I have a main.scss file which imports a partial sasss file (@import 'customMediaQueries'). When i update the customMediaQueries.scss file , the customMediaQueries.css is getting updated but the main.scss file which imported the customMediaQueries.scss file is not getting changed. Hence the resulting main.css is not getting updated.

I am using sassystudio. If anyone has any idea regarding this issue, kindly let me know.

Answer (score 0):

Renaming your file to *yourfilename.scss will compile the code to the main.css file. If there no '* or underscore' character in the beginning of the filename of the file you are importing in the main scss file, it will compile to another file by its own name, youfilename.css. Hope this helps.